# Does NUnit work with .NET 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, nunit

I'm just getting started with learning about Unit testing (and TDD in general).  My question is does the latest version of NUnit support working in VS2008 with .NET 3.5?  I've looked at the documentation pages at NUnit and they don't mention it.

If anyone has worked with it in 3.5 are there any limitations or features that don't work/need workarounds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using nUnit with 3.5. As long as you have a version that works with 2.0 you should be fine - same CLR and all that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

.Net 3.5 is mostly re-packaging and marketing. The .Net core within .Net 3.5 is actually .Net 2.0.

So any utility that you find for .Net 2.0 you can also apply to .Net 3.5.

For NUnit this means that the .Net 2 version is the one that you want.

Comment: I think .net 3.0 is mostly repackaging. .net 3.5 actaully added some more syntax fun like object and collection initializers. If you want to call compiler updates repackaging, then I guess it fits that description.

Answer (score 1):

No limitations that I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Version [2.5.5](https://launchpad.net/nunitv2/+announcement/5667) works with .NET 4.0 as well.

If you're just starting out, you should know that NUnit is going through some significant changes too.  You can see from [the new home page](https://launchpad.net/nunit-xtp) that they are maturing NUnit to include some of the new features in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Check the steps to follow at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/365fd6ef-0fa5-4eeb-b2d5-7c2f795b1f8c?prof=required